# How to pass sets of inputs variables to a function in R?

Tags: r, function, set, arguments, combinations

Good day,

I am trying to learn how to easily feed various sets of inputs to a function.
Each set of input is like the characteristics of an object.
The function should be able to run calculations given the choice of objects and accept other arguments too.

Let's illustrate this with a simplified example about groceries.

The function `basket()` can accept fruits that have a `value` and a `sugar_amount`. I can decide to place any number of fruits in the basket, and I want to return the total value and the sugar amount.

The function `basket()` should retrieve each fruit's `value` and `sugar_amount` from a dataframe or an external CSV file, for example. This data could be structured in this way:

```
        value  sugar_amount
APPLE      10            20
BANANA      5            10 
CHERRY     15            25
```

The function can accept several combinations of fruits, allowing the user to pick up to three fruits in our example (the number of available fruits), but can decide to select one or two kinds.
The user can also specify how many of each fruit he wants to put in his basket (`n1` for the first fruit, `n2` for the second, and so on).

```
basket <- function (fruit1, n1,
                    fruit2, n2,
                    fruit3, n3) {
   total_value = (fruit1$value * n1) + (fruit2$value * n2) + (fruit3$value * n3)
   total_sugar = (fruit1$sugar_amount* n1) + (fruit2$sugar_amount* n2) + (fruit3$sugar_amount* n3)
   }
```

An example calculation would be:

```
mix1 <- basket(APPLE, n1 = 1, CHERRY, n2 = 2)

      total_value  total_sugar   
mix1           40           70
```

As you can tell, this would not work as such since it is what I am trying to understand...
What should I do to have the possibility of calling any fruit combination I want?
Something related with `do.call()`?

If to go a bit further, I also wondered how to feed several sets of inputs to a function. Is it possible to use a list of mixes and use a sort of `lapply()` function to achieve this:

```
      total_value  total_sugar   
mix1           40           70
mix2           60           15
mix3           20           50
```

(Given that each mix is a different combination and quantity of fruits)

This is all new to me and I have not found an answer online so far.
Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: Pass your fruits and quantities in a list.  For example `basket(list("apple"=1, "cherry"=2))`.  Then interrogate the list within your function to obtain the required result, perhaps by converting the list to a data frame and then joining the "list df" with the "sugar df".  To solve your "several sets" problem, `basket` could interropgate each element of the list.  if the list is itself a list, `basket` could call itself recursively, with the current element of the list as the argument.

Comment: You use language such as "specifying the number of fruit" but you don't explain **how** that would be specified - is this a programmer passing an object? A drop down list from Shiny, as you discussed? If the latter, you'll receive the most benefit from framing it in terms of that and specifying in more detail what you think the app should look like and do - sketches of what you mean and pseudo-code are welcome. However, the basic answer will be that all of this should go into lists.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. @socialscientist: The number of fruits is passed to the argument n1, n2, etc.

Comment: You will need more detail, as discussed, to get beyond what Limey said.

Comment: @socialscientist: I've removed the mention of the Shiny app so that the questions focus only on the possibility of passing objects like lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to understand how vectorized and list-wise functions work in R. See [here for examples](https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-gapminder/09-vectorization/index.html) that can help.

However, to directly address your question, we could implement what you want per below.

## Get rows from data.frame based on vector of values

```r
library(dplyr)

# Create your underlying "database"
df <- data.frame(
  fruit = c("apple", "banana", "cherry"),
  value = c(10, 5, 15),
  sugar_amount = c(20, 10, 25)
)

# Create a function that takes a *vector* of fruit names and returns the
# value and sugar amount. Length of vector doesn't matter.
basket <- function(database, fruit_vector) {
  # Subset database to matching fruit
  database %>%
    filter(fruit %in% fruit_vector)
}

# Pass it two fruits found in the database
basket(df, c("apple", "cherry"))
#>    fruit value sugar_amount
#> 1  apple    10           20
#> 2 cherry    15           25

# Pass it 1 fruit in the database and 2 NOT in the database
basket(df, c("apple", "kiwi", "grape"))
#>   fruit value sugar_amount
#> 1 apple    10           20
```

## Use vectors to operate on a data.frame

```r
# Create a function that takes a vector of fruits and an
# equal-length vector of quantities to produce functions
# of those quantities and database values for the fruits
# specified in the vector
compute_totals <- function(database, fruits, quantity) {
  # Stop and report error if fruits and quantity aren't same length
  if (length(fruits) != length(quantity)) {
    stop("Fruits and quantity must be same length.")
  }
  
  # Build a data.frame from arguments
  inputs <- data.frame(fruit = fruits, quantity = quantity)
  
  # Add value and sugar amount to it
  joined <- left_join(inputs, database, by = "fruit")
  
  # Calculate total sugar and total value by fruit
  by_fruit <- joined %>%
    transmute(
      fruit = fruits,
      total_sugar = quantity * sugar_amount,
      total_value = quantity * value
    )
  
  # We can store that in a list for the output, as well
  # as get the totals for the mix and store it in the list
  # so our function returns both
  by_mix <- by_fruit %>%
    summarise(total_sugar = sum(total_sugar),
              total_value = sum(total_value))
  
  # Store in and return list
  list(by_fruit, by_mix)
  
}

# Examples - typical use
compute_totals(df, c("apple", "banana"), c(2, 3))
#> [[1]]
#>    fruit total_sugar total_value
#> 1  apple          40          20
#> 2 banana          30          15
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   total_sugar total_value
#> 1          70          35
compute_totals(df, "cherry", 100)
#> [[1]]
#>    fruit total_sugar total_value
#> 1 cherry        2500        1500
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   total_sugar total_value
#> 1        2500        1500

# Demonstrate error message by passing 2 fruits, 3 quantities
compute_totals(df, c("apple", "banana"), c(2, 3, 4))
#> Error in compute_totals(df, c("apple", "banana"), c(2, 3, 4)): Fruits and quantity must be same length.
```